# Selenium Grid2 Port not working only on port 4444

Tags: c#, selenium-grid2

I have set up Selenium Grid2 and I have a dilemma that is driving me crazy.

If I start the Hub in the default port (4444), for some reason all my HTTP requests are redirected to a page that says

> You are using grid .0.0Find help on
>   the official selenium wiki : more help
>   here

This happens in all browsers and in any application that connects to the internet.

If I change the port to anything else, the problem doesn't occur, but then tests in Internet Explorer (IE8 specifically) no longer work. They fail with an error about not being able to find an element.

This also happens with a non-grid setup, just using the server (selenium-server-standalone-2.0rc3.jar) except instead of the grid message all HTTPS connections are untrusted.

Any ideas?

Comment: yes, i've also tried it with the latest compiled version, same results

Comment: so I tried it at home and it works perfectly, even with other ports. Firewall maybe? Not sure how to track down the problem

Comment: I am also having the same problem. But I didnt try at home. But I was not having this issue in rc3 version. Had it only in the latest compiled one

Answer (score 0):

That's the page you get when you fetch the "/" resource.  But any page you care about almost certainly sits on another context.  Here's the relevant portion from the Hub's code:

`root.addServlet("/*", DisplayHelpServlet.class.getName());`

```
  root.addServlet("/grid/console/*", ConsoleServlet.class.getName());
  root.addServlet("/grid/register/*", RegistrationServlet.class.getName());
  // TODO remove at some point. Here for backward compatibility of
  // tests etc.
  root.addServlet("/grid/driver/*", DriverServlet.class.getName());
  root.addServlet("/wd/hub/*", DriverServlet.class.getName());
  root.addServlet("/selenium-server/driver/*", DriverServlet.class.getName());
  root.addServlet("/grid/resources/*", ResourceServlet.class.getName());

  root.addServlet("/grid/api/proxy/*", ProxyStatusServlet.class.getName());
  root.addServlet("/grid/api/testsession/*", TestSessionStatusServlet.class.getName());

  // Selenium Grid 1.0 compatibility routes for older nodes trying to
  // work with the newer hub.
  root.addServlet("/registration-manager/register/*", RegistrationServlet.class.getName());
  root.addServlet("/heartbeat", Grid1HeartbeatServlet.class.getName());
```

Do you have your nodes connecting to the correct URL?  They should be started with something like `-hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register` to register properly.

Comment: That is how I am registering the nodes. I don't want to jinx it, but I think the latest release (2.0.0) fixed the problem